# dynamic navigation list menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a small application and I basically need a list of 5 items say

Name
Address
City 
Country
Zipcode

Whenever the user clicks on anyone of these he needs to be directed to another page and that particular item needs to be highlighted.

I want to do this dynamically. I have an idea that it can be done with javascript [document.getelementbyid()] but dont know exactly how.

Comment: is "Name, Address, City, Country Zipcode" item's text , item's value , id or what ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you trying to do something like this:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

take a look at the AJAX example to get content from other pages